# What is the “single pulse radiometer equation”?

Tags: astronomy, radio-frequency, radio, radiometry

This document https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.03547 refers to the “single pulse radiometer equation”. Apparently, it’s used to calculate the flux of radio transients. What is the “single pulse radiometer equation”?

Comment: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjZ2LnJkq3qAhUMv54KHb3BDzgQFjACegQIARAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fcontent%2Fpdf%2Fbbm%253A978-3-642-19627-0%252F1.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1jfq9ii2ZZrvvHo5MfflO9 may help

Comment: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/20353/radiometer-equation-for-flux-density has not been answered (yet).

Answer (score 0):

The single pulse radiometer equation is a way to go from the signal-to-noise ratio of a detected pulse to its intrinsic flux density (see [Cordes & McLaughlin 2003](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2003ApJ...596.1142C/abstract)). This is handy because the regular radiometer equation assumes you're sampling a continuous signal over some integration time $\tau$; for a lone pulse from a source like a fast radio burst or a rotating radio transient, you've just got a short, isolated pulse.

Let's say we've got a pulse of intrinsic amplitude $A_i$ and some characteristic width $W_i$, with a flux density $S_i=A_iW_i$. Using the matched filtering search technique, it should be detected -- in the absence of extrinsic broadening -- with an SNR of
$$\mathrm{SNR}_i=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{W_n}}\left(\frac{A_i}{\sqrt{W_i}}\right)$$
where $W_n$ is some noise correlation time and the noise $\sigma$ itself is given by the radiometer equation:
$$\sigma=\frac{S_{\mathrm{sys}}}{\sqrt{n_p\Delta\nu W_n}}$$
with $S_{\mathrm{sys}}$ the system flux density, $n_p$ the number of polarizations measured (typically either $n_p=1$ or $n_p=2$) and $\Delta\nu$ the receiver bandwidth. You can substitute the latter equation into the former and cancel out some factors.

Now, the intrinsic characteristic width $W_i$ is not what we really observe; the pulse is broadened as it travels because of effects from the interstellar medium and potentially the telescope itself. Our first equation tells us that $\mathrm{SNR}_i\propto A_i/\sqrt{W_i}$; the same should be true for the broadened pulse, which will have the same area but a larger width. This allows us to convert the SNR we'd get from just the intrinsic pulse to the SNR we actually get after pulse broadening.

I'll leave it to you as an exercise to do the algebra to change this into an expression that gives you $S_i$ as a function of the SNR of the broadened pulse $\mathrm{SNR}_b$, but the answer -- the useful form of the single pulse radiometer equation -- should look something like the version used in [Patel et al. 2018](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2018ApJ...869..181P/abstract):
$$S_i=\frac{\beta\;\mathrm{SNR}_b(T_{\mathrm{sys}} + T_{\mathrm{sky}})}{GW_i}\sqrt{\frac{W_b}{n_p\Delta\nu}}$$
Note that this form includes 1) a correction factor $\beta$ of order ~1 to correct for digitization, 2) the telescope gain $G$ since the system flux density has been converted to system temperature, and 3) a sky temperature term added to the system term, which we don't have to really worry about in the derivation.